# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' to database '/path/to/Database"')

Tags: python, django, database, mariadb

I have tried dropping all users and databases and re-creating. I have granted all privileges to my user. I have made sure my settings.py includes the correct setup... for the record here is what I have:

```
DIR_FOR_DB = '/path/to/'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DIR_FOR_DB+ 'Database',
        'USER': 'someuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I can't think of any reason why it's not letting me in.

Comment: Hello, there seems to be a problem with your config, can you send it without renaming the fields?

Comment: the fields in my post are renamed to be consistent with the renaming in the error message in my title. I have triple checked that for typos so the renaming for this post shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: for real RDBMS, you must pass the database __name__, not a path (this "path" thing is for SQLite only). And you want to either pass the correct port, or not pass it at all.

Comment: Sorry @Cm1602 I meant the values. It seems to me that you need a port for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Database',
        'USER': 'someuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '8000',
```

You need to specify a port and not have a path on the database name.

Comment: To get this to work for me, I had to change the port to 3306. I got my port from a working interface to my database. I didn't try it without specifying the port at all.